# The agconnect-services.json File Content Cannot Be Obtained When Integrating the HMS Core SDK to a Unity-based Game

Tags: unity-game-engine, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

Recently, my project team integrated the HMS Core SDK for a Unity-based game.
But after integrating the HMS Core SDK in Android Studio and generated a JAR file. **The agconnect-services.json file downloaded from AppGallery Connect could not be used in Unity.**
what can i do with these error message?

Comment: I have tried to modify the manifest file by adding the following code.</br>

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following steps：

1. Save the JSON file obtained from AppGallery Connect to the **Plugins/Android** directory of Unity.

[image]

2. As Unity provides the HMS Core SDK plug-ins and a demo app, place the **AfterBuildToDo** script in the demo app in the **Editor** folder of your own project.

[image]

URL for downloading the Unity demo app:

https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/HMSSDKSample

The script is stored in **Assets/HuaweiHms/src/Editor/AfterBuildToDo.cs.**